# How is coverage percentage calculated when branch coverage is enabled in coverage.py

Tags: code-coverage, coverage.py, test-coverage

I am using coverage.py tool to get coverage of python code. If I use the command without --branch flag like below,

```
coverage run test_cmd
```

I get the coverage report like this,

```
Name                                                                              Stmts   Miss  Cover
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
/path/file.py                                                                      9      2    78%
```

From this I understand that the cover percentage value is derived as this

```
cover = (Stmts Covered/total stmts)*100 = (9-2/9)*100 = 77.77%
```

But when I run coverage with --branch flag enabled like this

```
coverage run --branch test_cmd
```

I get the coverage  report like this,

```
Name                                                                           Stmts   Miss Branch BrPart  Cover
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
/path/file.py                                                                    9      2      2      1    73%
```

From this report I am not able to understand the formula used to get Cover=73%

How is this number coming and is this correct value for code coverage?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While you probably shouldn't worry too much about the exact numbers, here is how they are calculated:

Reading from the output you gave, we have:

```py
n_statements = 9
n_missing = 2
n_branches = 2
n_missing_branches = 1
```

Then it is calculated (I simplified the syntax a bit, in the real code everything is hidden behind properties.)

https://github.com/nedbat/coveragepy/blob/a9d582a47b41068d2a08ecf6c46bb10218cb5eec/coverage/results.py#L205-L207

```py
n_executed = n_statements - n_missing
```

https://github.com/nedbat/coveragepy/blob/8a5049e0fe6b717396f2af14b38d67555f9c51ba/coverage/results.py#L210-L212

```py
n_executed_branches = n_branches - n_missing_branches
```

https://github.com/nedbat/coveragepy/blob/8a5049e0fe6b717396f2af14b38d67555f9c51ba/coverage/results.py#L259-L263

```py
numerator = n_executed + n_executed_branches
denominator = n_statements + n_branches
```

https://github.com/nedbat/coveragepy/blob/master/coverage/results.py#L215-L222

```py
pc_covered = (100.0 * numerator) / denominator
```

Now put all of this in a script, add `print(pc_covered)` and run it:

```
72.72727272727273
```

It is then [rounded](https://github.com/nedbat/coveragepy/blob/8a5049e0fe6b717396f2af14b38d67555f9c51ba/coverage/results.py#L135-L149) of course, so there you have your `73%`.

Comment: Thanks @Kaligule for the explanation and the links, still for some the files I am not able to calculate the coverage with this, where [Stmts   Miss Branch BrPart  Cover] are [ 64     49     22      0    22%] or [360    170    150      6    48%]

Comment: I have now generated json report from there I can get the exact values of missing branches and can use the formulae to see the percentage